# Calculate activity interval for a pandas DataFrame with datetime rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Given the following DataFrame of pandas in Python:

Displays the switching on and off of 3 light bulbs at different times using date and time objects.

```
                        date       ID_bulb     switch       using_time
1  2022-03-27 15:30:21+00:00             1        ON               NaT
2  2022-03-29 17:05:21+00:00             1       OFF   2 days 01:35:00
3  2022-04-07 17:05:21+00:00             1       OFF               NaT
4  2022-04-06 16:10:21+00:00             2        ON               NaT
5  2022-04-07 15:30:21+00:00             2       OFF   0 days 23:20:00
6  2022-02-15 23:10:21+00:00             3        ON               NaT
7  2022-02-16 02:10:21+00:00             3       OFF   0 days 04:00:00
8  2022-02-16 02:50:01+00:00             3        ON               NaT
9  2022-02-18 10:50:01+00:00             3       OFF   2 days 07:00:00
10 2022-02-04 19:40:21+00:00             4        ON               NaT
11 2022-02-06 15:35:21+00:00             4       OFF   1 days 19:55:00
12 2022-02-23 20:10:21+00:00             4        ON               NaT
13 2022-02-24 02:10:21+00:00             4       OFF   0 days 10:00:00
14 2022-03-14 12:10:21+00:00             5        ON               NaT
15 2022-03-15 00:10:21+00:00             5        ON               NaT
16 2022-03-16 05:10:21+00:00             5       OFF   0 days 05:00:00
```

I want to add a new column, called `cost_days`. This column will include only for rows where the variable `using_time` is different from `NaT`. Information on how many times the light bulb has been on during at least `n` hours in a row between a night period defined by `start_time` to `end_time`.

Example of the resulting DataFrame:

Given for example:

```
add_costdays_column(df, 5, "22:00:00", "07:00:00")
```

```
                        date       ID_bulb     switch       using_time    cost_days
1  2022-03-27 15:30:21+00:00             1        ON               NaT         0
2  2022-03-29 17:05:21+00:00             1       OFF   2 days 01:35:00         2
3  2022-04-07 17:05:21+00:00             1       OFF               NaT         0
4  2022-04-06 16:10:21+00:00             2        ON               NaT         0
5  2022-04-07 15:30:21+00:00             2       OFF   0 days 23:20:00         1
6  2022-02-15 23:10:21+00:00             3        ON               NaT         0
7  2022-02-16 02:10:21+00:00             3       OFF   0 days 04:00:00         0
8  2022-02-16 02:50:01+00:00             3        ON               NaT         0
9  2022-02-18 10:50:01+00:00             3       OFF   2 days 08:00:00         2
10 2022-02-04 19:40:21+00:00             4        ON               NaT         0
11 2022-02-06 15:35:21+00:00             4       OFF   1 days 19:55:00         2
12 2022-02-23 20:10:21+00:00             4        ON               NaT         0
13 2022-02-24 02:10:21+00:00             4       OFF   0 days 06:00:00         0
14 2022-03-14 12:10:21+00:00             5        ON               NaT         0
15 2022-03-15 00:10:21+00:00             5        ON               NaT         0
16 2022-03-16 05:10:21+00:00             5       OFF   0 days 05:00:00         1
```

Only the row ON before the row OFF with a value other than `NaT` in the `using_time` column is taken into account for switching on the bulb. This is to simplify the problem, I will adapt it later to the specific case.

Comment: Why the value for 1 days 19:55:00   is   2?

Comment: Do you want to count the number of nights the blub has been on in the specified period?

Comment: @keramat The ```cost_days``` counter increments by 1, each time ```n``` (5) consecutive hours pass within the specified interval (22:00:00 to 07:00:00).

Comment: @Carola Is `using_time` of pandas suitable for this rule `22:00:00 ~ 07:00:00`？

Comment: @lazy Let's say the time interval is from ```2022-02-16 02:50:01+00:00``` to ```2022-02-18 10:50:01+00:00```. In that period you have to count how many periods of 5 hours in a row there are between 22:00:00-07:00:00 each day. In this case 1, one for the night of the 17th to the 1st.

Comment: @Carola I see. I want to know if this column`using_time` has been calculated.

Comment: If `using_time` has been calculated, we don't need to consider the time rule.

Comment: The ```using_time``` column is the difference between the ```date``` of the OFF row and the previous ON row.

Comment: Is the value of the index 9 is correct? it is more than two day but you count it just one time. There is more than one specified time range within this time.

Comment: @keramat You are right, I have changed it!

Comment: So, look at my answer and see if it helps or not.

Comment: @keramat I can't see your reply posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('TEST_STACK.csv')
df = df.iloc[:df[df['using_time'].notna()].index[-1]+1]
#solution
g = (df['using_time'].notna()).sort_index(ascending=False).cumsum()
g = (g-max(g)).abs()
import numpy as np
def rounder(x):
      v = pd.date_range(list(x)[-2], list(x)[-1], freq='1h')
      temp = pd.Series(v, index = v).between_time('22:00', '07:00')
      temp = len(temp)/9
      return np.floor(temp) if np.mod(temp, 1.0) < 6/9 else np.ceil(temp)/9
temp = df.groupby(g)['date'].apply(lambda x: rounder(x))
df.loc[df[df['using_time'].notna()].index, 'new col']=temp.values
df['new col'] = df['new col'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: Could you print the Output with the same structure as I have indicated in the post? Please

Comment: Check the answer now.

Comment: Some associated errors: ```rounder(len(pd.Series(pd.date_range(list(x)[-2], list(x)[-1], freq='1h'),```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: A different one, but it has the same structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245422/discussion-between-carola-and-keramat).

Comment: There are cases where there is less than two rows. In other words there is not -2 index there.

Comment: Did your problem solve?

Comment: No, check the private chat, I have written several questions.